# loading content via ajax into a textarea with tinymce installed

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have the following script pulling in data from a wordpress database. It all works fine when selecting different options (pulls in the correct data etc).

I have now installed tinymce editor onto the textarea. Since this the content no longer shows.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#myselect').change(function()
            {
                var selected = $(this).find(':selected').html();
                var id = $(this).find(':selected').val();
                $.post('http://www.xxx/admin/email/ajax.php', {'beverage': selected, 'id':id }, function(data) {
                  $('#result').html(data);
                });
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Does anyone know what i am missing to make this work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself, i needed to change the following:

```
$('#result').html(data);
```

to:

```
tinyMCE.get('result').setContent(data);
```